# Are you allowed to make references to things like Jedi or The Walking Dead (those are just examples) or do you need permission?

Tags: creative-writing

Will I get sued or something if I just mention/ reference something like that?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/27756/is-it-permitted-to-mention-a-real-life-work-of-fiction-in-your-story?rq=1

Comment: Agreed, this looks like a duplicate. Angel, if there's anything not answered by [this question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/27756/is-it-permitted-to-mention-a-real-life-work-of-fiction-in-your-story), please edit your question to differentiate it and we'd be happy to consider reopening.